# reorder great number of columns in a text file

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, pattern-matching

I need a method (awk/perl/sed/shell) to modify the contents of a file as below:

Before:

```
123456|ABCDEF|123|011|A|E|NULL|R|UNKNOWN|A1|A2|B1|B2|C1|C2|2013|2013|9999|Y
```

After:

```
123456|ABCDEF|123|011|A|E|NULL|R|UNKNOWN|9999|Y|A1|B1|C1|NULL|NULL|NULL|2013|2013
```

I need to move the last 2 columns after the 9th column, remove the columns 11,13, 15 and also insert the `NULL|NULL|NULL` in between the 14th and 15th columns (`C1|2013`). Any tips appreciated. `cut` command cannot change the order of insertion, so will need to go another way. The input file has 10 million such rows and i'm looking for the best way to do this.

Comment: All rows have same number of columns?

Comment: Look into `awk` and changing the field separator, `FS`.  http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Field-Separators.html

Comment: Pls let me know why this was closed? What is off-topic ??

Comment: `perl -F'\|' -alne'splice@F,15,0,("NULL")x3;$,="|";print @F[0..8,20,21,9..19]'`

Answer (score 4):

Ugly question calls for ugly solution:

```
awk -F"|" '{
    for(i=1;i<=9;i++) { printf "%s|" ,$i }
    printf "%s|%s|",$(NF-1),$NF
    for(i=10;i<16;i+=2) { printf "%s|" ,$i }
    printf "%s|%s|%s|","NULL","NULL","NULL"
    for(i=16;i<(NF-2);i++) { printf "%s|" ,$i }
    print $(NF-2)
}' inputFile
```

Answer (score 2):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed -r 's/((\w+\|){9})(\w+\|)\w+\|(\w+\|)\w+\|(\w+\|)\w+(\|\w+\|)(\w+)\|(\w+\|\w+)/\1\8|\3\4\5NULL|NULL|NULL\6\7/' file
```

---

```
$cat file
123456|ABCDEF|123|011|A|E|NULL|R|UNKNOWN|A1|A2|B1|B2|C1|C2|2013|2013|9999|Y

$sed -r 's/((\w+\|){9})(\w+\|)\w+\|(\w+\|)\w+\|(\w+\|)\w+(\|\w+\|)(\w+)\|(\w+\|\w+)/\1\8|\3\4\5NULL|NULL|NULL\6\7/' file
123456|ABCDEF|123|011|A|E|NULL|R|UNKNOWN|9999|Y|A1|B1|C1|NULL|NULL|NULL|2013|2013
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` for this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{print $1,$2,...,"9999|Y",..."NULL|NULL|NULL",...'
```

`$1` is the first field, `$2` the second, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Don't want count your columns, but you can get the idea from the next perl script:

```
perl -F'/\|/' -lanE 'say join("|", $F[2], "NULL", "NULL", $F[0], $F[3], $F[1])'
```

for the input

```
123456|ABCDEF|123|011
```

produces

```
123|NULL|NULL|123456|011|ABCDEF
```

tha `autosplit` mode splits each line on the `|` character and you can reorder the fields anyhow you need. the `join` joins fields together with the `|`.

For fun - pure bash - and slow :)

```
while IFS='|' read -r a b c d
do
echo "$a|NULL|$d|$c|NULL|$b"
done << EOF
123456|ABCDEF|123|011
EOF
```

prints

```
123456|NULL|011|123|NULL|ABCDEF
```